# How to override projectile keybind for custom one?

Tags: projectile, prelude, helm-projectile

I am currently using emacs out of `prelude` and with `helm-projectile` enabled in my setup.

Recently I added `helm-ls-git` to my stack too and noticed that the function `helm-browse-project` is more interesting for me than the one I've been using previously `helm-projectile-find-file` (from `helm-projectile`) bound to `C-c p f`.

Under my `config/personal.el` I've added the following line and thought it should do the trick:

`(global-set-key (kbd "C-c p f") 'helm-browse-project)`

This is not working, but if I switch to another unused key binding such as `C-c p 0` for instance, it works perfectly fine.

So, why can't I override it and what should I do in order to make that happen?

Answer (score 3):

If you(or `prelude` maker) set it up as explained on the  `projectile`(wrapped by `helm-projectile`) home([github.com](https://github.com/bbatsov/projectile#quickstart)), you'll bind the internal `projectile-command-map` to this minor-mode's `projectile-mode-map` with the prefix key `C-c p` in your Emacs config like this:

```lisp
(define-key projectile-mode-map (kbd "C-c p") 'projectile-command-map)
```

In this case the target map to change for your own binding is neither `global-map` you first tried nor `projectile-mode-map` just for defining the prefix key to call the command map, but the command map itself is what should be changed and the following code will do the trick:

```lisp
;; overwrite the command map for the key "f" (after the prefix key "C-c p")
(define-key projectile-command-map (kbd "f") 'helm-browse-project)
```

Answer (score 0):

Load order matters. The latest `global-set-key` overrides the former ones. Make sure yours is evaluated after the one you want to override.

Answer (score 0):

There are several different keymaps active for any Emacs buffer: the major-mode, any minor-modes, a buffer-local keymap, and the global keymap. The global keymap has the lowest priority - if a keybinding is defined in any of the other active keymaps, that's the binding that will be applied when you hit those keys.

In your case, `C-c p f` is bound in the keymap for a minor or major mode, so binding that key in the global keymap doesn't do anything useful. You can see a list of all the active keybindings for a buffer with the `C-h b`. Scroll through that to find the keymap where that sequence is bound. That's the one you need to modify, not the global keymap.

Comment: Usually the buffer local keymap is defined by the major-mode via `use-local-map`.